# Ubuntu и Visual Studio Code gdb изменение комбинаций клавиш по умолчанию

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

Можно ли настроить "Visual Studio Code или gdb" таким образом, чтобы "шаг внутрь" игнорировал "Библиотечные функции" и отрабатывал только мои функции на f11.